# How do I add an Iframe Block in Grapejs?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, grapejs

I want to let my users add Iframe-Content to their page that they create via GrapeJS.
For this I want to add an IFrame-Block to the GrapeJS editor, but I'm struggling to get it to work. Can anybody help?

- There is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510895/how-to-add-iframe-in-grapesjs), but it only works for an older version of grapejs.
- There is [this plugin](https://github.com/omarmd1986/grapesjs-blocks-avance/), but it also doesn't work for the current version
- There should be a [FrameComponent](https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/blob/master/src/dom_components/model/ComponentFrame.js), but If I define a block with type "iframe", I get 'TypeError: m.render is not a function'

Answer (score 1):

This was solved in the newest version
https://github.com/artf/grapesjs/releases/tag/v0.20.1

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33065600)